# Xcode libraries warnings after update

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase

I recently updated xcode and have gotten a large amount of warnings all of the similar format.  They're all mainly in gRPC and similar libraries.

They usually look like this

```
- (void)enqueueValue:(id)value completionHandler:(void (^)())handler;
```

And the warning is

```
This block declaration is not a prototype, insert void
```

But when I do xcode breaks itself and turns the warning into an error. I'm assuming the syntax is off the self corrector can't quite figure out what is wrong.  Below are a few other examples of this warning for context

```
GRPCAPI gpr_timespec grpc_max_auth_token_lifetime();
```

-

```
+ (NSEnumerator *)grx_enumeratorWithValueSupplier:(id (^)())block;
```

-

```
- (void)handleLossWithHandler:(nullable void (^)())lossHandler
      wifiStatusChangeHandler:(nullable void (^)())wifiStatusChangeHandler;
```

Comment: You've tagged this question with Swift but all of the code you posted is Objective-C code.

Comment: My mistake I took this from the library files which are obviously objective-C even tho my actual code is swift.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This is a known issue being addressed in upcoming grpc releases.

Comment: Awesome thank you!  would you happen to have links to any discussions on the topic and will I need to get specific zip files from github to update (or is there a simpler way)?

Comment: @AaronMann It's kind of scattered - but all the work should be visible in https://github.com/grpc/grpc